# UISearchBar Sometimes Resigns When Tapping On Views

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uigesturerecognizer

My view controller setup is as follows: `UISearchBar` on top of screen, keyboard on the bottom, and other views between them: custom `UIView`, `UIView`, `UITableView`. When I tap on the table view cells and `UIButton`s inside `UIView`s, I can trigger my actions successfully while keeping `UISearchBar` still visible on screen. But when I tap on `UIView`s that do not have buttons, this triggers `searchBarShouldEndEditing` as if search bar loses the focus. I want to disable this behavior and let only Cancel button and keyboard's Done button to trigger `UISearchBar` closure.

I thought this has to do with bubbling effect and tried to implement this fix:

```
extension UIViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return touch.view == gestureRecognizer.view
    }
    @IBAction func didTap(_ gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer ) {
        //
    }
```

but this did not address the issue and `UISearchBar` still calls `searchBarShouldEndEditing`. Of course, I could add logic to `searchBarShouldEndEditing` to return `false` but not sure this is effective enough.

How can I ensure `UISearchBar` remains in place while tapping on other elements like `UIView`s?

Comment: what did you set the UITableView keyboard dismiss mode as?

Comment: UITableView keyboard dismiss mode stays default which is _Do not dismiss_